# how to add object from one key NSDictionary in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I have one `NSDictionary` and one `NSMutableArray` And I want store many object from `NSDictionary` into `NSMutableArray` from one key but I dont know about it.

this is my code :

```
//NSArray * a = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"7",@"9", nil];
//NSArray *b = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"0", nil];
NSDictionary * dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:a,@"number1",b,@"number2", nil];

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray alloc].... ?
```

I want store object in number1 key from `NSDictionary` in `NSMutableArray`

Comment: `[array addObject:dic[@"number1"]];`?

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that you store arrays as `NSDictionary` elements, you can do this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initiWithArray:dic[@"number1"]];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:dic[@"number1"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

To add object into `NsDictionary` Array do:

```
NSMutableDictionary * datos = [array objectAtIndex:i];
[datos setObject:@"hola" objectForKey@"newKey"];
```